# Calculate the rotational period automatically in python

Tags: python

I am beginner in programming and I use python. I have a code that calculate the rotation period of star, but I have to change the star ID each time, which will take me effort and time to complete it.
Can I change the star ID automatically?

```
from lightkurve import search_lightcurvefile
lcf = search_lightcurvefile('201691589').download()  ## star Id = 201691589
lc = lcf.PDCSAP_FLUX.remove_nans()
pg = lc.to_periodogram()
Prot= pg.frequency_at_max_power**-1
print Prot
```

I saved all 'stars_ID' that I want to use in a txt file(starID.txt) with 10000 lines, and I want  to calculate the rotation period (Prot) in an automatic way so that the code takes the star ID from the txt file one by one and do the calculations, then save the star_ID and Prot  in a csv file (two columns: 'star_ID', 'Prot'). Can you please help me do it.

Comment: Is the `plot()` in `pg.smooth().plot()` relevant here? That's going to be problematic for 10000 plots if it tries to show them in a loop.

Comment: No it is not necessary,  I will cancel the plot(). What matters to me is the calculation of Prot.

Answer (score 1):

This should get you close but I don't have a bunch of star IDs handy, nor is this in my field.

The main points:

1. Use the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module for reading and writing files.
2. When you have code that you need to call many times (well, oftentimes even just once for a logical grouping), you want to consider packaging it into a [function](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/functions-python-tutorial)

There are other pointers for you to research. If I didn't try and make things a little more succinct than basic loops then the code would be quite long, and I tried to not make it too terse. Hopefully it's enough for you to follow up on.

```
from lightkurve import search_lightcurvefile

import csv

# You need to read the file and get the star IDs. I'm taking a guess here that
# the file has a single column of IDs
with open('starID.txt') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    # Below is where my guess matters. A "list comprehension" assuming a single 
    # column so I just take the first value of each row.
    star_ids = [item[0] for item in reader] 


def data_reader(star_id):
    """
    Function to read periodogram for a star_id

    Returns [star_id, periodogram]
    """

    lcf = search_lightcurvefile('201691589').download()
    lc = lcf.PDCSAP_FLUX.remove_nans()
    pg = lc.to_periodogram()
    Prot= pg.frequency_at_max_power**-1

    return [star_id, Prot]


# Now start calling the function on your list of star IDs and storing the result
results = [] 
for id_number in star_ids:
    individual_result = data_reader(id_number) # Call function
    results.append(individual_result) # Add function response to the result collection


# Now write the data out
with open('star_results.csv', 'w', newline='') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    writer.writerows(results)
```

Answer (score 0):

You said 'beginner' so this is an answer for someone writing programs almost for the first time.

In Python the straight-forward way to change the star id each time is to write a function and call it multiple times with different star ids.  Taking the code you have and changing into a function without changing the behavior at all might look like this:

```
from lightkurve import search_lightcurvefile

def prot_for_star(star_id):
  lcf = search_lightcurvefile(star_id).download()
  pg = lcf.PDCSAP_FLUX.remove_nans().to_periodogram()
  return pg.frequency_at_max_power**-1

# Now use map to call the function for each star id in the list
star_ids = ['201691589', '201692382']
prots = map(prot_for_star, star_ids)
print(list(prots))
```

This could be inefficient code though.  I don't know what this `lightkurve` package does exactly, so there could be additional ways to save time.  If you need to do more than one thing with each `lcf` object, you might need your functions to be structured differently.  Or if creating a periodogram is CPU intensive, and you end up generating the same ones multiple times, there could be ways to save time doing that.

But this is the basic idea of using abstraction to avoid repeating the same lines of code over and over again.

Combining the original star id with its period of rotation can be achieved like this.  This is a bit of functional programming magic.

```
# interleave the star ids with their periods of rotation
for pair in zip(star_ids, prots):
  # separate the id and prot with a comma for csv format
  print(','.join(pair))
```

The output of the Python script can then be stored in a csv file.

Comment: The issue you'll have with `wavelengths = map(frequency_for_star, star_ids)` is that you need a nested list to write back out to the CSV. You can fix that with `return [star_id, pg.frequency_at_max_power**-1]`